# UINavigationBar background color not appearing as solid color

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

I'm trying to change the background color of statusbar and UINavigationBar Using appDeligate file but somehow changed color does not appear as Solid color it is appearing with some gradient from the start please refer to below image [image: IOS APP UINavigationBar Color]    this what i have declared in AppDelegate in **didFinishLaunchingWithOptions** function

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159/255, green: 31/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 100)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
```

This what I have declared in my plist file     [image: My plist file]
  Please help me out here I tried all searching everywhere but could not find any solution

Comment: You can set UINavigationBar.appearance().isTranslucent = false

Answer (score 0):

Thank you, everyone, after being looking for answer to change the tabbar color I found the answer to this question earlier my my AppDelegate was .

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 159/255, green: 31/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 100)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
```

Now I changed this to

```
UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor(red: 159/255, green: 31/255, blue: 99/255, alpha: 100)
UINavigationBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.white
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor:UIColor.white]
```

and my problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Check the Translucent property of the bar Style color.